# React Recoil - Call Delete API Endpoint async on Set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, recoiljs

I am just trying to get to grips with React Recoil to replace Redux in my application. I want to be able to Delete a *Season* record so have set the following:

**Selector Family**

```
export const deleteSeason = selectorFamily({
  key: "deleteSeason",
  set:
    () =>
    async ({ get, set }, seasonId) => {
      return await seasonApi.deleteSeason(seasonId);
    },
});
```

Where `seasonApi.deleteSeason` carries out the actual API call.
The Select-Family is referenced here:

```
const setSeasonDelete = useSetRecoilState(deleteSeason());
```

And called in an async function here:

```
 const onDeleteSeason = async (selectedSeason) => {
    setInEditMode(false);
    try {
      await setSeasonDelete(selectedSeason.Id);
    } catch (error) {
      deleteSeasonFailNotification("error");
    }
  };
```

When the method is called (from a button click) the API Appears to be hit and the DB deletes the record, however the TRY-CATCH drops out with the error:

*`"Recoil: Async selector sets are not currently supported."`*

I presume there is a better/correct way of doing what I am trying to do so any help is greatly appreciated.